# Push view controller from List in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am in learning phase of `SwiftUI`

during which I have created one tab view which has 4 tabs, out of which on last tab, there is list which has following array

```
struct NavItem {
    let id: String
    let text: String
}

struct ServicesView: View {

    @State private var listItems: [NavItem] = [NavItem(id: "1", text: "Profile"),
                                                      NavItem(id: "2", text: "Leave"),
                                                      NavItem(id: "3", text: "How to use"),
                                                      NavItem(id: "4", text: "About Us"),
                                                   NavItem(id: "5", text: "Logout")]
```

Using `LIST` I am able to display the same in view correctly, only problem I am facing is I am not able to push the new on selection of any item

```
 var body: some View {

                NavigationView {
                    List (selection: $selection) {
                                ForEach(listItems, id:\.id) { item in
                                    Button(action: {
                                        if(item.id == "1"){
                                            print("navigate to ----> " + item.text)
                                            NavigationLink(destination: ProfileView()) {
                                                Text("Show Detail View")
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }) {
                                        Text(item.text)
                                            .foregroundStyle(.black)
                                    }
                                    .padding(10)
                                    .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0,leading: -5, bottom: 0, trailing: -5))
                                    .frame(minWidth: 111, idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                    .tag(item.id)
                                    .background(Color.clear)
                                }
                            }
                }
}
```

When I add navigationLink inside LIST, it gives me warning like below,

```
Result of 'NavigationLink<Label, Destination>' initializer is unused
```

I am able to print on console, but my list is not navigating to Profileview.

Can anyone will please help me to understand what I am doing wrong.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `NavItem` declaration is missing. You can’t return a View in the action closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NavigationLink` represents a kind of a View, it's not a function to execute when you put it in Button action. You have to bring it out of closure.

**Updated:** There is a condition to trigger push action to `ProfileView`, so this is a trick:

```swift
@State private var isActive: Bool = false
...
NavigationView {
    List {
        ForEach(listItems, id:\.id) { item in
            Button {
                isActive = item.id == "1"
            } label: {
                Text(item.text)
                    .foregroundStyle(.black)
            }
        }
    }
    .background {
        NavigationLink(destination: ProfileView(), isActive: isActive) {
            EmptyView()
        }
        .hidden()
    }
}
```

**Note**: `NavigationView` was deprecated, you may consider using `NavigationStack` instead.

```swift
@State private var path: NavigationPath = .init()
...
NavigationStack(path: $path) {
    List {
        ForEach(listItems, id:\.id) { item in
            Button {
                if item.id == "1" {
                    path.append(item)
                }
            } label: {
                Text(item.text)
                    .foregroundStyle(.black)
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationDestination(for: NavItem.self) { item in
        ProfileView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @son, that worked and as directed I used navigationstack only. Thanks